# Sharing Wired Internet over WiFi via Laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, smartphone

I have a wire-based Internet connection for my laptop and I have a smartphone which I want to connect to Internet.

The laptop has WiFi but I don't know how I make my LAN traffic available to then connect my smartphone to wlan through wifi.

The OS's I am trying this are Windows 7 (a domain machine), and Windows Vista (workgroup machine).'

well it involves smartphone

Comment: I have windows 7 and windows vista on my laptps

Comment: are you running android on that smartphone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadband cable to wireless](http://superuser.com/questions/44981/broadband-cable-to-wireless) also see [How to share an internet connection? (Peer to Peer Network)](http://superuser.com/questions/27388/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-peer-to-peer-network?rq=1)

Comment: I wouldn't call this question a duplicate since we are dealing with a smartphone (probably android) whereas the other questions are simply dealing with sharing connections between computers.

Answer (score -1):

Go to manage network connections in control panel.

Select the two connections and choose "Bridge Connections".

You will need to setup your wireless network as AdHoc once it's bridged the two together.

Comment: android is not friendly twards ad-hoc.

Comment: i tried that ..somehow my phone does not detect that network..and in pc it shows "local only" means no internet...further before bridging if you select "share this network for internet access..blah blah" it does not allow to bridge the devices..

Comment: would routing work? i don't know how to configure that...

Comment: My understanding is that bridging should work but if, as mentioned above, Android doesn't play nicely with ad-hoc networks then you're out of luck. What about buying a very cheap wireless cable router and use that?

Comment: yeah...that would be the obvious choice now but i think some solution should be there built in the os

Comment: Bridging IS built into the OS!

Comment: yeah just does not work with android